# how to use IndexOf on an arraylist of class

Tags: java

I have an arraylist of Sprite,

```
public class World {
ArrayList<Sprite> sprites;
}

public class Sprite {
      public Sprite(String image_src, float x, float y) {
 }

 public class Stone {
      public stone(String image_src, float x, float y) {
 }
```

How do I use IndexOf on this sprites in World class to get the first instance with class name Stone?

Comment: `sprites.indexOf(someSprite)` ?

Comment: Well ... The [method's documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf-java.lang.Object-) explains how to use it. Anything unclear there?

Comment: Make sure the `Sprite` class has correct overrides of `equals` and `hashCode`.

Comment: `sprites.indexOf(new Sprite("my string value", 0.0, 1.0))`

Answer (score 2):

From official [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf-java.lang.Object-)

> The java.util.ArrayList.indexOf(Object) method returns the index of the first occurrence of the specified element in this list, or -1 if this list does not contain the element.

Don't forget to implement equals (and hashCode ) in the Sprite class